# How do I use global configuration variables within "Action" arguments?

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

After setting up a copy of the *Inventory > Actions > Deploy Using PS*/DSC (Standard Server) action I can't figure out how to use a global configuration variable in the argument list.

### The global variables I would like to use:

(*from Administration > Settings > Configuration Variables*)

[image: Global Variables]

### The argument list where I would like to use them:

(*from Inventory > Actions > Deploy Using PS/DSC (Standard Server)*)

[image: PowerShell Deployer Argument List]

Within my PowerShell Script I can reference these variables by using the "$" in front of the variable name, but this doesn't work in "Action" argument lists.

### Example Usage from a PowerShell Script

`[System.IO.Path]::Combine($ServerName,$ApplicationPathRoot,$ComponentName)`

## Unknowns

Is using a configuration variable even possible within the *Action* arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The "Configuration variables" at the System level are only available for vNext release templates. Actions are for agent-based releases, not for vNext releases. Thus, you can't use them.

The idea behind vNext templates is that the actions in your release take place entirely within PowerShell/DSC/Chef scripts -- there's no need to add custom actions, since all of the actions should be source controlled script files.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response. The action that I have in the screen shots is actually a copy of the PowerShell DSC action so it can be used in a vNext release.What I would like to do is use the System Variables in the argument list for that action so that I can re-use what I have setup, specifically an encrypted password. This saves me from entering the password each time I use that action in each release template.